# How can I compare random number in elm

Tags: random, elm

I use  `float : Signal a -> Signal Float` to generate random number.

I want to compare this generated number with a `Float`, how can I do that?

```
main = lift asText ((Random.float (fps 24)) < 0.3)
```

This is wrong, error message:

```
    (Random.float (fps 24)) < 0.3

    Expected Type: Bool
    Actual Type: Signal.Signal a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to debug this type of thing is to follow the types. Break every part into a separate piece, examine the types and resolve the type error.

We have a few things here:

```
lift : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
asText : a -> Element
Random.float : Signal a -> Signal Float
fps : number -> Signal Time
(<) : number -> number -> Bool
```

Okay, so let's start plugigng in values and resolving the types:

```
fps 24 : Signal Time
Random.float (fps 24) : Signal Float
(Random.float (fps 24)) < 0.3 : ???
```

This is where our type error is coming from. We are trying to pass in a Signal but the `(<)` operator only accepts `number`. So, what we actually want is a function that compares the value in our `Signal` to see if it is `< 0.3`.

```
foo : Float -> Bool
foo n = n < 0.3
```

Now, we can lift `foo` and pass the signal into it:

```
lift foo (Random.float (fps 24))
```

And then plug it back into our original expression:

```
main = list asText (lift foo (Random.float (fps 24)))
```

Now, all of the types resolve.

Hope this helps!

Comment: then how can I use this True & False in conditions? 
It seems I cannot do something like this: `main = if (lift foo (Random.float (fps 24))) then asText "1" else asText "2"`

Comment: something like this again?
`foo' b = if b then "1" else "2"
main = foo' <~ (foo <~ (Random.float (fps 24)))`

Comment: if expressions are formed "if Bool then a else a" so you need a Bool in the space where b is. However, Random.float (fps 24) is type Signal Float. To make your example work you would need something like `foo' b = if b < 0.3 then "1" else "2"`. The secret is to annotate the type of `foo'` so the compiler can tell what you're trying to do `foo' : Float -> String`

Comment: can you also answer this question? Thanks!